# How can I expand widget Expandable ListView to 10 layers?

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandable

I'm developing a Expandable ListView up to 10 layers .

I am using the following code to the second layer could only go forward .

I have used the following code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try{
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);

    SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =
        new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
                this,
                createGroupList(),              // Creating group List.
                R.layout.group_row,             // Group item layout XML.           
                new String[] { "Group Item" ,"level"},  // the key of group item.
                new int[] { R.id.row_name ,R.id.row_name2}, // ID of each group item.-Data under the key goes into this TextView.                   
                createChildList(),              // childData describes second-level entries.
                R.layout.child_row,             // Layout for sub-level entries(second level).
                new String[] {"Sub Item","level"},      // Keys in childData maps to display.
                new int[] { R.id.grp_child,R.id.grp_child2}     // Data under the keys above go into these TextViews.
            );

        setListAdapter( expListAdapter );       // setting the adapter in the list.

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

/* Creating the Hashmap for the row */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List createGroupList() {
      ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
      for( int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; ++i ) { // 15 groups........
        HashMap m = new HashMap();
        m.put( "Group Item","شماره گروه " + i ); // the key and it's value.
        m.put( "level","لایه اول " );

        result.add( m );
      }
      return (List)result;
}

/* creatin the HashMap for the children */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private List createChildList() {

    ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
    for( int i = 0 ; i < 15 ; ++i ) { // this -15 is the number of groups(Here it's fifteen)
      /* each group need each HashMap-Here for each group we have 3 subgroups */
      ArrayList secList = new ArrayList(); 
      for( int n = 0 ; n < 3 ; n++ ) {
        HashMap child = new HashMap();          
        child.put( "Sub Item", "شماره زیر گروه " + n );
        child.put( "level", "لایه دوم ");
        secList.add( child );
      }
     result.add( secList );
    }        
    return result;
}
public void  onContentChanged  () {
    System.out.println("onContentChanged");
    super.onContentChanged();         
}
/* This function is called on each child click */
public boolean onChildClick( ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,int childPosition,long id) {
    System.out.println("Inside onChildClick at groupPosition = " + groupPosition +" Child clicked at position " + childPosition);
    return true;
}

/* This function is called on expansion of the group */
public void  onGroupExpand  (int groupPosition) {
    try{
         System.out.println("Group exapanding Listener => groupPosition = " + groupPosition);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(" groupPosition Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Please any solution that comes to your mind in this context to give me.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile

Output my program following image is the:

[image]

Comment: Any help on either of these is greatly appreciated!